# Unknown OpenCV exception while using EasyOcr

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, easyocr

Code:

```
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('R.png')
```

Output:

```
CUDA not available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.

cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

I would truly appreciate any support!

Comment: send bug report to easyocr maintainer/developer

Comment: Switch to 4.5.4.60 Opencv version Opencv latest release have a problem with easyocr. 
@joseph-k

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new version of OpenCV has some issues. Uninstall the newer version of OpenCV and install the older one using:

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.4.60
```

Comment: This answer is literally Hiren Namera's comment.

Answer (score 0):

install letest version of opnecv

**pip install opencv-python==4.5.4.60**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).